# How to fix network change was detected (ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED)?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, configuration

I recently changed my internet provider. Since then, I'm always getting the following error when navigating to any page and or web-based systems:

```
Your connection was interrupted
A network change was detected.
ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, however, my system doesn't use netplan. My NUC PC has no wireless configuration. Some sites I visited says it could be something related to IPV 6. Here's my interfaces content:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhpc
```

and here's my ifconfig results:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2804:14c:f281:9e79::1000  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2804:14c:f281:9e79:7954:9135:a069:fa8a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2804:14c:f281:9e79:dc23:6375:9767:5475  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::b3db:3343:c0b6:7eb6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c0:3f:d5:8f:89:f8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 282871  bytes 224815101 (224.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 198386  bytes 43246824 (43.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7c00000-f7c20000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 14883  bytes 1776993 (1.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14883  bytes 1776993 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 and later, `/etc/network/interfaces` is deprecated and no longer used. I suggest that you revert your changes and simply let Network Manager do the job. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.